# JSON Schema oneOf doesn't work with references

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

Schema is for a message with the header properties and then either properties of `msg1` or `msg2`:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

    "definitions": {
        "header": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "token":         { "type": "string" },
                "id":            { "type": "number" }
            },
            "required": ["token", "id"]
        },
        "msg1": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "content1":         { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["content1"]
        },
        "msg2": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "content2":         { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["content2"]
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/header",
    "oneOf": [
       {"$ref": "#/definitions/msg1" },
       {"$ref": "#/definitions/msg2" }
    ]
}
```

So this should pass:

```
{
    "token": "abc123",
    "id": 333,
    "content1": "s"
}
```

The problem is that the following passes:

```
{
    "token": "abc123",
    "id": 333
}
```

How to fix it?

(of course, there are a lot more of `msg#`s and they have different structure)

Comment: what validator you are using? By spec if object has $ref other keywords should be ignored (and you have $ref on the top level). So it may be that oneOf is ignored. But different validators implement it differently.

Comment: @esp, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything other than the `$ref` is getting ignored.

> Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.
>
> - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03

You can fix the problem by wrapping `$ref` in an `allOf`.

```
"allOf": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/header"}],
```